# Nordic nRf905 (433MHZ) with arduino receive garbage data

Tags: arduino-uno

I am interface Arduino with nRf905 in receive mode use 433 MHZ.

I Have follow this link http://www.electrodragon.com/w/NRF905_Transceiver_433MHz-Wireless_Module.

And for transmitter, I am use RF-Transmitter-Door-Window-Sensor which works on 433MHZ.

Now, Arduino receive garbage data I have attached snapshot of received data.

I am quarry about to set address and 433MHZ.

My config_buffer is:

```cpp
unsigned char config_info_buf[10]={
      0x4C,
      0x01,                   //output power 10db, resend disable, Current 
      0x44,                   //4-byte address
      0x20,0x20,              //receive or send data length 32 bytes
      0x21,0x11,0x11,0x00,
      0x18,
};
```

Question is there are 0x4C set exactly 433MHZ.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards,
rajneesh

Comment: This is far too incomplete to be answered.  You must provide full details of wiring, power, and transmit and receive software.

Comment: Your question `Question is there are 0x4C set exactly 433MHZ.` doesn't make a lot of sense. You should try to be more specific in what you are asking.
However a couple of pointers for troubleshooting:
1) Is the TX side set to transfer ASCII/Text data ?
2) Are you sure the baud rate is the same on the RX arduino and the PC you using the serial monitor on ?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have provided all details in above post.  Wiring connection with arduino and nRF905 => TXEN=5;
    TRX_CE=4;
    PWR=3;
    CSN=10;
    AM=9;
    DR=8;
    CD=7; MOSI = 11; MISO 1;SCK=13; Ya I have checked baud rate of arduino and pc bath are same. As a transmitter device I have used https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/RF-100m-transmission-distance-wireless-Magnetic_60286055162.html?spm=a2700.7724857.0.0.ov1gVH  .This is work on 433MHz. Still I am confuse If AM and DR pin set to high then why I am receive garbage data?